# PHP remove element contain specific class

Tags: php, regex

I need help using preg_replace

First, I want to remove the  anchor element and leave only the text.
I use this regex : '#<a .*?>|#'
and it seems to work.

then I want to remove an element that contains a certain class and I haven't found the right regex for it. I tried using this : '#<td class="*remove-this.*td>?#ms' but still failed

this is the code:

```
function prp($str)
{
    $anchor = '#<a .*?>|</a>#';
    $remove = '#<td class="*remove-this.*td>?#ms';
    $str = preg_replace($anchor, '', $str);
    $str = preg_replace($remove, '', $str);
    return $str;
}

$tags = '<td class="hello there">
            <a href="#" class="hy">Thank you</a>
        </td>
        <td class="hello there remove-this">
            <a href="#" class="hy yuhu">Yuhuuu</a>
        </td>';

print_r( prp($tag) );
```

The output i want is:

```
<td class="hello there">
Thank you
</td>
```

how to get it?

Comment: Don't parse HTML with regexes, just use a DOM parser, like the one that's included in PHP.

Comment: I need a fast process
using a DOM parser takes longer than expected

Comment: previously i managed to remove it when that element had only "remove-this" class, but when it was started by another class then things got messed up

Comment: How fast do you need this to be? A parser would be much easier. `class="*remove-this.*td` will only match `class="remove...` or `class=""""""""remove` or `class=remove` likely you are missing `.` on the quantifier but this is likely to be a huge mess down the road. These regexs are veryyy loose and will create invalid mark up.

Answer (score 0):

```
function prp(string $html, array $classesToRemove): string {

  $doc = new DOMDocument();
  $doc->loadHTML($html);

  $htmlNode = $doc->childNodes[1];
  $bodyNode = $htmlNode->childNodes[0];

  foreach ($bodyNode->childNodes as $node) {
    if (( $node->nodeType === XML_ELEMENT_NODE ) && $node->tagName === 'td') {
      foreach ($node->attributes as $attribute) {
        if ($attribute->nodeName === 'class' && in_array($attribute->nodeValue, $classesToRemove)) {
          $bodyNode->removeChild($node);
        }
      }
    }

  }

  return str_replace([ '<body>', '</body>' ], '', $doc->saveHTML($bodyNode));

}

$tags = '
<td class="hello there">
<a href="#" class="hy">Thank you</a>
</td>
<td class="hello there remove-this">
<a href="#" class="hy yuhu">Yuhuuu</a>
</td>
';

print_r(prp($tags, [ 'hello there remove-this' ]));
```

Comment: oh man, thank you so much you helped me,
I've tried it and it worked,
but it takes longer than expected

the good news i have found the solution

Answer (score 0):

@lukas.j got me excited again and I'm trying to find information about PHP DOM

and this is the solution as expected

```
function prp($str)
{
    $str = "<tr>{$str}</tr>";

    $anchor = '#<a .*?>|</a>#';
    $str = preg_replace($anchor, '', $str);

    $doc = new DOMDocument;
    @$doc->loadHTML($str);
    $xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
    $el = $xpath->query("//td[contains(@class, 'remove-this')]");
    if($el){
        $el = $el[0];
        $rel = $el->ownerDocument->saveXML($el);
        $str = str_replace($rel, '' , $str);
    }
    $tr = '#<tr.*?>|</tr>#';
    $str = preg_replace($tr, '', $str);

    return $str;
}

$tag = '<td class="hello there">
            <a href="#" class="hy">Thank you</a>
        </td>
        <td class="hello there remove-this">
            <a href="#" class="hy yuhu">Yuhuuu</a>
        </td>';

print_r( prp($tag) );
```